# Bypassing workplace HTTP proxy (using SSH, or other)

Tags: ssh, http, https, sshd, http-proxy

1. The workplace proxy (from here *workproxy*) is on port 8080; it requires NTLM authentication.  I've been able to achieve this using NTLMAPS.  I've tested NTLMAPS using all of my browsers, and the manual NTLM authentication works fine.  The proxy seems to allow *some* HTTPS (port 443) connections, as I'm able to bank within the country, but not with a foreign bank.
2. I've setup a home machine (let's call it *homesvr*), also Windows, to run an SSH server on port 443, everything with regards to the SSH server works.  (I'm running it on Cygwin).
3. On the work machine I have Cygwin, and I'm attempting to SSH to *homesvr* using the following settings --

~/.SSH/config:

> Host *
>          ProxyCommand corkscrew localhost 5865 %h %p /home/WinUser/.SSH/home.auth

~/.SSH/home.auth:

> HomeWinUser:HomeWinPass

**SSH -v *homesvr* -p 443** output is ...

> OpenSSH_5.8p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011
>   debug1: Reading configuration data /home/WinUser/.ssh/config
>   debug1: Applying options for *
>   debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
>   debug1: Executing proxy command: exec corkscrew 127.0.0.1 5865 *homesvr* 443 /home/WinUser/.ssh/home.auth
>   debug1: permanently_drop_suid: 400
>   debug1: identity file /home/uidb5693/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
>   debug1: identity file /home/uidb5693/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
>   debug1: identity file /home/uidb5693/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
>   debug1: identity file /home/uidb5693/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
>   debug1: identity file /home/uidb5693/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
>   debug1: identity file /home/uidb5693/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1

*pause*

> ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host

It seems as though the connection is established, but it is not authenticating properly with *homesvr* and hence timing out on login.  Removing the home.auth file from .ssh/config results in the same behavior.

This has frustrated me for nearly a week.  Any advice is highly appreciated.

Comment: Assuming it doesn't require authentication because you don't get prompted probably isn't a good idea.  If you are on a domain at work your browser could be silently passing your NTLM credentials.

Comment: It seems as though you are absolutely right about the NTLM credentials being passed to the _workproxy_.  I've successfully used [ntlmaps](http://ntlmaps.sourceforge.net/) to authenticate "manually", by running a local proxy (ntlmaps) and passing it my correct plain text credentials.  Now instead of receiving the Proxy Authorization Required error, the terminal hangs on the debug message right before that and doesn't give me any chance to enter my password on the SSH server.  It seems as though I've done the hard part, I've bypassed the proxy and connected, now I just need to forward the output

Comment: Standard disclaimer: you're responsible for the consequences if you get in trouble with your IT department or management for trying to bypass their proxy.

Comment: Check [sslh](https://github.com/yrutschle/sslh), _Applicative Protocol Multiplexer (e.g. share SSH and HTTPS on the same port)_

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
ssh -D 8888 yourname@serveroutside
```

if serveroutside listens on 443 do

```
ssh -D 8888 -p 443 yourname@serveroutside
```

Then make your browser use socks proxy v5 on localhost port 8888 and you are good to go.

Answer (score -1):

you should try [openvpn](http://openvpn.net)  at homesrv then connect through it